# Does Neo4j support complex property types?

Tags: neo4j

I have some complex property types such as polygon in my RDBMS, and I want to convert them into neo4j, but in reading the official documentation, I find that the property type should be bool/byte/short/int/log/float/double/char/string. I am wondering, does neo4j support complex property types?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how "complex" the data needs to be. In addition to the scalar types that you listed, a neo4j property can also contain an array of one of those types.

So, for instance, you could store the coordinates of an N-vertex polygon in an array of size 2*N, where each X/Y pair is stored as consecutive numbers. No "complex" type is really needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information~But I am still wondering, an array has fixed length, if my "complex type" has variable length, is the conversion effective?

Comment: It is certainly possible to use the data in a variable length list to create a fixed-length neo4j collection. The exact details depend on your language and/or driver.